# Woocommerce get_cart in theme function.php get error message "get_cart() on null"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Bellow is code that I use to get products from cart

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
```

I have this code inside functions.php in theme folder.

The issue is every time I run this code, I always get error message saying

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null"

What did I miss ?

Comment: This code need to be used only on front end templates or hooked functions, **as cart is a live object related to current customer**… So you should add the complete code where you are using this code and give more details. Note: `WC()` replaces oldish `global $woocommerce;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($items as $item => $values) 
{ 
    $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
    echo "<b>".$_product->get_title().'</b>  <br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
    $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
    echo "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your code is valid, however you are probably calling it from the backend or somewhere where there is no cart. you might be looking to process order items from an order?

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

// Iterating through each WC_Order_Item_Product objects
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values):

## Using WC_Order_Item methods ##

// Item ID is directly accessible from the $item_key in the foreach loop or
$item_id = $item_values->get_id();

## Using WC_Order_Item_Product methods ##

$item_name = $item_values->get_name(); // Name of the product
$item_type = $item_values->get_type(); // Type of the order item ("line_item")

endforeach;
```